# S3 meta data key values reset after each upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci

I am uploading my s3 content from travis and every time the upload completes, the meta data key values are reset.

I need to keep the 'Content-Encoding' key set to 'gzip'.  How is it possible to control this from my travis build file or is there something more persisting I can do on the bucket itself?

Comment: Seems to me the aws api supports uploading files with meta tags but travis has yet to implement this.  If it has I am unable to find the documentation for it.  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis issue was fixed and content-encoding is now supported. See github issue,

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2400

Example:

```
deploy:
  provider: s3
  detect_encoding: true
  # other s3 stuff
```